# Remove padding in horizontal progress bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, android-constraintlayout

In our application we need an indeterminate progress bar, like so:

[image: progress bar how it should be]

We can achieve this by setting a negative margin on the ProgressBar, like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:marginTop="-7dp"
    android:visibility="@{loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

**BUT** because ConstraintLayout does not support negative margins, it will look like this:

[image: progress bar with padding]

OK, the negative margin was a hack. Let's replace it with a different hack, shall we? Let's introduce our custom view `CustomProgressBar`, which extends `ProgressBar` and overrides its `onDraw` method, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int marginTop = dpToPx(7);
    canvas.translate(0, -marginTop);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But all of this smells like bad code. There has to be a better solution!
What would you recommend?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use a Guideline and center ProgressBar between the parent top and the guideline.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="-4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="4dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually did the trick! I varied the answer a bit by setting `app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="9dp"` on the guideline and only setting `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"` (not constraintBottom or padding) for the progressbar – works. Still feels hacky to me, but I feel it's the best option currently.

Answer (score 21):

Solution that feels less like a hack: Wrap a huge `ProgressBar` in a smaller `FrameLayout`. That way the `FrameLayout` constrains its height, but the `ProgressBar` still shows in full.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: another solution is
<ProgressBar style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" android:layout_height="4dp"/>

Comment: It just sucks we need to do this just for something so simple.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem as well. And like you said, I come across numerous solutions which all seem like a hack that might break something else down the line.
With that said, I came across one solution which is to use this [library](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar) instead for progress bar.

One thing to note is, it tells you to integrate it by adding:

```
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
```

However, when I used this, it gave me an error from an Android support library for Floating Action Bar. So I'll recommend you to use this instead:

```
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
```

A sample code snippet on how I used it:

```
<me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/reviewProgressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    app:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal"
    app:mpb_useIntrinsicPadding="false"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

A *dirty* workaround I did was set the height of the ProgressBar closely to the to stroke width like so:

Progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading_progress"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2.1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tb_browser"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_browser_progress_drawable"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Progress drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Which looked like this:

[image]

Comment: For me thats a good answer. No need to handle in the layout itself with -paddings or sth. 

When you add the values to the dimensions xml, which is then more understandable. +1

Comment: doesn't that only work for determinate, not indeterminate? The OP talks about indeterminate.

Comment: @John61590 The OP did use indeterminate in his question. But the focus of the question was on removing the padding (hence the title), which shouldn't really matter whether your progressbar is determinate or indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

You declared your view without any explicit height so it's height is being picked from the pre-defined style.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:marginTop="-7dp"
    android:visibility="@{loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

"?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" will be searched in current theme and is stored in attrs.xml file. Since this defined by the platform it will obtain it's the value from there. As of writing this answer, I'm on  android platform 29 and searching "?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" gives the following results

```
➜  values 
pwd
/Users/vihaanverma/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/data/res/values
➜  values 
grep -rin "progressBarStyleHorizontal" . 
./themes_device_defaults.xml:126:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./themes_device_defaults.xml:857:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./themes.xml:272:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./themes_holo.xml:263:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./themes_holo.xml:626:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./public.xml:148:  <public type="attr" name="progressBarStyleHorizontal" id="0x01010078" />
./themes_material.xml:258:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./themes_material.xml:635:        <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.Material.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
./styles_material.xml:1010:        <item name="progressBarStyle">?attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal</item>
./attrs.xml:684:        <attr name="progressBarStyleHorizontal" format="reference" />
➜  values
```

Opening one of the files which contain "progressBarStyleHorizontal"  you will see minHeight defined in the style and is equal to 16dp.

```
<style name="Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_material</item>
    <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_material</item>
    <item name="minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

This is the cause of the extra padding you are getting. You can fix it by giving your view height and a scaleY value like below

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:scaleY="5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use inside Linearlayout and you will success, the simple way

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```